# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - Linker error when building webrtc Qt for Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, webrtc

**I’m trying to make a build for Mac desktiop in Qt Creator using WebRTC native library but always see the error message:**

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSOSStatusErrorDomain", referenced from:
      rtc::DescriptionFromOSStatus(int) in libwebrtc.a(logging_mac.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSError", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libwebrtc.a(logging_mac.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libwebrtc.a(thread_darwin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSThread", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libwebrtc.a(thread_darwin.o)
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::InitCocoaMultiThreading() in libwebrtc.a(thread_darwin.o)
      rtc::Thread::PreRun(void*) in libwebrtc.a(thread_darwin.o)
      rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages(int) in libwebrtc.a(thread_darwin.o)  …. 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [lib*******_WebRTCWrapper.1.0.0.dylib] Error 1
12:17:39: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.10.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

***Initial parameters:***

- Qt Creator Based on Qt 5.10.0 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit)
- Compiler - Clang (C++ x86 64 bit) in c++11 mode against libc++
- MacOS - Sierra v.10.12.6
- Xcode - Version 9.2 (9C40b)
- WebRTC - branch-heads/63

**After playing with compilation options of webrtc, I have compiled with system's clang and using libc++.**

**I have builded the webRTC library with parameters:**

- gn gen out/x64/Debug --args='is_debug=true target_os="mac" is_component_build=false rtc_include_tests=false target_cpu="x64”’
- export GYP_DEFINES="build_with_libjingle=1 build_with_chromium=0 libjingle_objc=1 clang=1 clang_xcode=1 use_system_libcxx=1 OS=mac"
- export GYP_GENERATORS="ninja, xcode-ninja"
- export GYP_DEFINES="$GYP_DEFINES OS=mac target_arch=x64"
- export GYP_GENERATOR_FLAGS="$GYP_GENERATOR_FLAGS output_dir=out/x64/Debug”
- ninja -v -C out/x64/Debug

**Moreover after extensive googling I have edited *common.gypi* file in /src/build/**

```
'xcode_settings': {
           'GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC': 'NO',               # No -mdynamic-no-pic
                                                     # (Equivalent to -fPIC)
           'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY': 'libc++',
           # MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET maps to -mmacosx-version-min
                    }

'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI': 'YES',             # -fno-rtti
```

```
'GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS': 'NO',     # -Werror
```

```
'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY':           'libc++', # -stdlib=libc++
```

**But unfortunately, the result error is the same!!!**

Comment: Are you building in Debug mode, did you try _release_ mode directly?

Comment: are you sure you re not missing the "Foundation" framework when linking ?

Comment: Yeah! You're right! The problem was in including "Foundation" framework. I'm very appreciate for your help! Thank's a lot!!